# VB.net help: On click (From image button), show image

Tags: asp.net, image, integer

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 btw, VB.net.

So I have an Imagebutton, and Image. What I want to do is when I click on Imagebutton, it loads up the image.

The thing is, I have 8 Imagebuttons, so the image must have a code to load up different images from my directory, which is the images folder from root.

This is the current code I have, which has an error.

```
Dim img As String
Image1.Visible = True
img = Image1.ImageUrl("/Images/Example.png")
```

The error is `"Conversion from string "/Images/Example.png" to type 'Integer' is not valid."`

So I changed `Dim img As Integer` now.

I get this error:

> 'Char' values cannot be converted to 'Integer'. Use 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW' to interpret a character as a Unicode value or 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val' to interpret it as a digit.

I am at a loss now.

Comment: Is code implemented in button's OnClick method? I didn't understand your code, can you show the complete method? Why did you do img = Image1.ImageUrl("/Images/Example.png")

Comment: @Samuel Yes the code was implemented in the button's OnClick (Webpage.aspx.vb). It's my first time doing declaring with image buttons and image that's why. I've only learned declaring with buttons and labels. I thought it would be the same but haha guess not :P I'm a little rusty on variables as you can see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is rised when you call `Image1.ImageUrl("/Images/Example.png")`

If you want to chance the Image in Image1 when you click in button use this.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Example.png"
```

and to set value form ImageUrl in img variable

```
img = Image1.ImageUrl
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was just what I needed. I knew there was something wrong with my code, but I was unsure of what it was. If only you posted this so much earlier! I ended up creating 8 web forms just to show the image when you click on the image button. It was a pain in the neck, but somehow I managed to complete my project. I will remember this code for future projects that I have. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ImageUrl property is the image that is displayed on the image button itself. If you want an image to be displayed on its own when the button is clicked then you need to set the image as the PostBackURL of the button.

e.g. `Image1.PostBackUrl="~/Images/Example.png"`